# linkedConfiguration not taking effect

Tags: .net, app-config, fusion, assembly-binding-redirect, assemblybinding

I have a .dll.config in which I'd like to place a `linkedConfiguration`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <linkedConfiguration href="file://C:\Directory\other.config"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</configuration>
```

Where other.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

When I run the application that references the dll, the assembly binding redirect is not honored. From fuslogvw:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/4/2020 @ 1:55:33 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Directory
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Directory\Test.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

If I copy the above runtime node into the .dll.config, the redirect is honored:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/4/2020 @ 2:02:36 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Directory
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Directory\Test.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.2.0.0 redirected to 4.2.1.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Does linkedConfiguration not work like I think it does or have any common gotchas? How can I get more information on what's going wrong?

Comment: you must copy to output directory the file  (copy to bin )

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I too am having this same problem. Even tried to copy the external config file to same directory with the bin.